# Using the optimized values from one Lingo model in another Lingo model

Tags: excel, mathematical-optimization, lingo

In lingo I have modeled a maximizing function and have found optimal values for say `x1,x2,x3`.The data required to this model is obtained through an EXCEL sheet by `=@OLE('C:\sheet1')`.  This maximization part works fine. For the second part now I have to use these optimal X1,X2,X3 which were found from this model and use some data in `C:\sheet1` and multiply `Xi's` with `sheet1` data and insert the resulting values in a column in `sheet1`.
How can I do this?
Do I have to do the second part in a separate LINGO file? If so how can I obtain the optimized values in first model ?
Or can I write two Models in one LINGO file? In this way does this help me to have the optimized values from part1 to be used for part2?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Lingo expert, but here are a few hints. You can use the `SUBMODEL` directive to define two submodels and then execute them in a `CALC` section. Between executing them, you can 'sandwich' your data-processing code:

```
SUBMODEL m1:
... define equations ...
ENDSUBMODEL

SUBMODEL m2:
... define equations ...
ENDSUBMODEL

CALC:
@SOLVE(m1)
... read in the new data from Excel ...
... do the data processing ...
@SOLVE(m2)
... output to Excel ...
ENDCALC
```

As for the data export to Excel, see [manual](http://www.lindo.com/downloads/PDF/LINGO14.PDF) (Lingo 14) page 451 for an example. `SUBMODEL` is documented on page 597.
These [lecture notes](http://www.uv.es/ivorra/docencia/LINGOav.pdf) also show many helful examples regarding the data processing (accessing variable values, modifying parameters, etc.)